# JQueryTooltip Wizard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a wizard style like: http://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-HZA3b/0/1?curriculum_id=50579fb998b470000202dc8b (when open page then it shows a tooltip with "NEXT" button on it which explains how to use the application)

I have searched for JQuery Wizard or Steps on Google but nothing similar found. I have tried to use http://thecodemine.org/# a formwizard and adapt to my website but with no result because it is for forms.

If this isn't the place to ask questions as this, please tell me to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also you can use http://linkedin.github.io/hopscotch/ for normal

or http://bootstraptour.com/ if you using bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try "Website Tour Plugin":

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/

It is similar to your recommended link.